# Android, Order of execution for Google Map and Location?

Tags: android, google-maps, location-services

I have an app with a Google Map, as per [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map) tutorial. I also am also getting the user's current location, as per [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) tutorial.

Both are using the most current API, as of 09/15.

The Google Map is located within a fragment, within the view. I've been trying to get the map to load with the user's current location from within the `public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map)` function, to only failed results and lots of *NullPointerExceptions*. Something like...

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    mLoadLocation = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());

    if(mLastLocation != null){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLoadLocation, 18.0f));
    }else{
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(37.422611, -122.0840577), 18.0f));
    }
}
```

But `mLastLocation` always returns NULL. So I moved the `moveCamera` call to `onConnected`, as follows

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLoadLocation = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLoadLocation, 18.0f));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This works a charm, exactly as I'd like it to. But will the map view *ALWAYS* be ready by the time `onConnected` is called? Or is this a device-by-device kind of thing? I want to preserve the functionality, regardless of the approach.

I've tried every SO method I could find for initiating the map with the user's current location, but none of them have worked. Lots of crashing and NULL values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleMap and FusedLocation both are different classes so their methods, so it's difficult to tell which method will be called first. It's better to call FusedLocation early and initialize mLastLocation or apply some default value with it. Then in onMapReady method move camera to either current location or default location of mLastLocation.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've got. The map defaults to the entire local zone where the user is, but zooms in on the location if assigned in time.

Comment: If accurate location is not your requirement then you may use LocationManage class to get immediate location with either GPS or Network Providers.